# How to Adjust So an Image Overlays the Slider

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, overlay

Looking to place a 230x200 image in the `<div class="float-left">` area to have it slightly overlay on the slider. Example being http://screencast.com/t/Jo9zYjnllHZ

In the website http://tinyurl.com/njencjc there is CSS that connects the slider and the header area where the logo is placed

```
.show-rev-slider #header .slider {
height: 380px;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Would this be a CSS addition or is PHP needed? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: css only,, just show css and html through jsfiddle or type in question!

Answer (score 0):

Both the logo and the slider will be in boxes so to speak example:

if you are trying to overlay the logo on top of the sliders, the all you need to do is find out what z-index the slider uses, this is the css that control levels of boxes within a website. The slider uses it to place each of the images on top of each other to allow the slider to work. You need to get the z-index level above the highest level of the slider to always be on top...

Answer (score 0):

This is your code : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1svwzk5k/)

- this is only css way to do it!
- just add **overlay** div inside slider `div` and `position` it!
- **Note -** you can change the dimentions! In code dimentions just for demo purpose!

**html**

---

```
 <div class="slider">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <img src="http://s28.postimg.org/uut7yirrx/00000472.png">
 </div>
```

**css**

---

```
    .slider {
        position:relative;
        border:1px solid #07a;
        margin:75px 50px;
    }
    .overlay {
        position:absolute;
        height:100px;
        width:178px;
        border:5px solid red;
        top:-58px;
    }
```

**Image SnapShot**

---

[image]